How do i fix error: Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled
I'm programming an esp32CAM in Arduino IDE to transfer video to a st7789 240x240 and I keep getting this error and I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:4688
load:0x40078000,len:15460
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:4
load:0x40080404,len:3196
entry 0x400805a4
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008ec35  PS      : 0x00060930  A0      : 0x8008ef8b  A1      : 0x3ffb20d0  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x00000002  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x00000001  A7      : 0x02625a00  A8      : 0xffffffff  A9      : 0x3ffb21c0  
A10     : 0x0000e101  A11     : 0x00000002  A12     : 0x00000404  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x00000001  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x0000000f  LBEG    : 0x40084299  LEND    : 0x400842a1  LCOUNT  : 0x00000027  


Backtrace: 0x4008ec32:0x3ffb20d0 0x4008ef88:0x3ffb20f0 0x4008e99d:0x3ffb2110 0x4008eb0c:0x3ffb2130 0x40083980:0x3ffb2150 0x400839a1:0x3ffb2180 0x40083ada:0x3ffb21a0 0x400837ac:0x3ffb21c0 0x400d95fd:0x3ffb21e0 0x400d5ba8:0x3ffb2200 0x400d5c7a:0x3ffb2220 0x400d22d0:0x3ffb2240 0x400daa16:0x3ffb2270 0x4008a98a:0x3ffb2290




ELF file SHA256: 11e550805

And here is the code thats not working
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include <SPI.h>

#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

TaskHandle_t Task1;

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();       // Invoke custom library
TFT_eSprite spr = TFT_eSprite(&tft);

camera_config_t config;

uint16_t *scr;
long initalTime = 0;
long frameTime = 1;
volatile bool screenRefreshFlag = true;

/////////////////////////////////
void Task1code( void * pvParameters ) {
  //core0 setup
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_240X240;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_RGB565;
  config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST;    //option CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY
  config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 2;                          //need more than 1 for latest grab

  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_brightness(s, 0);     // -2 to 2
  s->set_contrast(s, 0);       // -2 to 2
  s->set_saturation(s, 0);     // -2 to 2
  s->set_special_effect(s, 0); // 0 to 6 (0 - No Effect, 1 - Negative, 2 - Grayscale, 3 - Red Tint, 4 - Green Tint, 5 - Blue Tint, 6 - Sepia)
  s->set_whitebal(s, 1);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_awb_gain(s, 1);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_wb_mode(s, 0);        // 0 to 4 - if awb_gain enabled (0 - Auto, 1 - Sunny, 2 - Cloudy, 3 - Office, 4 - Home)
  s->set_exposure_ctrl(s, 1);  // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_aec2(s, 0);           // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_ae_level(s, 0);       // -2 to 2
  s->set_aec_value(s, 300);    // 0 to 1200
  s->set_gain_ctrl(s, 1);      // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_agc_gain(s, 0);       // 0 to 30
  s->set_gainceiling(s, (gainceiling_t)0);  // 0 to 6
  s->set_bpc(s, 0);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_wpc(s, 1);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_raw_gma(s, 1);        // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_lenc(s, 1);           // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_hmirror(s, 0);        // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_vflip(s, 0);          // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_dcw(s, 1);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_colorbar(s, 0);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable

  //core0 loop
  for (;;) {
    //take picture
    camera_fb_t  * fb = NULL;
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    //transfer frame buffer data to pointer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 57600; i++) {    //240x240px = 57600
      byte first_byte = fb->buf[i * 2];
      byte second_byte = fb->buf[i * 2 + 1];
      scr[i] = (second_byte << 8) + first_byte;
    }
    screenRefreshFlag = true;
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);   //return the frame buffer back to the driver for reuse
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup() {

  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(TFT_BLACK, TFT_WHITE);
  scr = (uint16_t*)spr.createSprite(240, 240);
  tft.drawString("Loading...", 105, 105, 2);
  
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    Task1code,   // Task function.
    "Task1",     // name of task.
    100000,      // Stack size of task
    NULL,        // parameter of the task
    1,           // priority of the task
    &Task1,      // Task handle to keep track of created task
    0);          // pin task to core 0

  delay(1000); 
}

//////////////////////////////////
void loop() {
  //refresh display if there is a new image from the camera
  if (screenRefreshFlag) {
    initalTime = millis();
    spr.drawString(String(frameTime), 100, 220, 2); //print frame time in milliseconds
    spr.drawString("ms", 125, 220, 2);
    spr.pushSprite(0, 0);
    screenRefreshFlag = false;
    frameTime = millis() - initalTime;
  }
}

Thank  you for the help in advance.
I tried to search on how to fix it but i'm relatively new to this so I got lost

Download and install ESP Exception Decoder to decode the backtrace and find out what exactly caused the exception panic.
